# New Azure Resources Show Up in Portal but not CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-static-web-app

After running a DevOps pipeline that created several resources, only two (a new resource group and a Functions app) show up in Azure CLI using `az ... list --subscription ...`.

Other resources, like Static Web Apps and a SQL Server don't show up in that list or when running `az staticwebapp list --subscription ...` or `az sql server list --subscription ...` with the subscription argument specified. I have confirmed that these resources DO show up in the portal, and my account is listed as an owner (inherited from subscription) for them in the portal.

Comment: How is your static web app deployed ?

Comment: The content is deployed as part of the same pipeline, but the Azure CLI is used to retrieve the API token, so deployment (of content)  fails now that this issue is occurring. The resources are all deployed as part of a single template, also via the Azure CLI in a pipeline task.

Comment: By using `az staticwebapp list --resource-group YourRGName` and `az staticwebapp list --subscription YourSubscriptionID` Iam able to get the StaticWeb App list

Comment: Check Images [Using ResourceGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Fov.png) and [Using Subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJyIb.png)

Comment: I'll also add that this issue has been coming and going, last night it went away without any clear cause and now it is back when deploying an identical pipeline (with new resource names to test a clean deployment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else running into this:

I have not found a solution to getting the `az staticwebapp list` command to work for my use case, as the results that show up immediately after creating a resource are just inconsistent. However, as a workaround that should satisfy most use cases, using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list-by-resource-group) API (using `az rest` command) to find all resources associated with the group created by the pipeline, then filtering those down to find the Static Web App I want, seems to work.

Then, when using other APIs that reference that app before it shows up in the normal list, fully specifying subscription and resource group alongside the app's name seems to make things more reliable too.

As far as I can tell, this is probably just a limitation with the inconsistency of how long information about newly deployed resources takes to propagate that shows up when trying to find a resource immediately after creating it.

Answer (score 0):

- I have deployed Azure Static WebApp using Azure Devops.
- Followed this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/publish-devops#:%7E:text=%20Create%20a%20static%20web%20app%20%201,editor%20for%20use%20in%20another%20screen.%0ANote%0AThis...%20More%20) to publish the static web app.
- By using,

```cs
az staticwebapp list --resource-group YourRGName
```

and

```cs
az staticwebapp list --subscription YourSubscriptionID
```

,Iam able to get the StaticWeb App list

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know this is supposed to show up when I use the CLI but those results just aren't there for me for some reason, whether specifying with resource group, subscription, both, or neither. Coming back to my desk later in the day and seeing this too, I still don't see anything.

Comment: What is your Azure Subscription Model ?

Comment: The portal says the plan type is "Azure Plan"